# Why would a switching voltage regulator circuit produce fluctuating voltage output?

Tags: circuit-design, switching-regulator, oscillation

I've created a circuit (image below) Using the LTC3623EUUD#TRPBF. The output should be 5v, however the voltage is oscillating up and down. What would be causing the oscillation?

I used solder paste and surface mount components for this.

[image]

Comment: If you're measuring the fluctuating voltage via a voltmeter only (no other consumption), yes I'd guess it's expected. Try adding some load and measure again.

Comment: What is the switching rate, and what is the period of the oscillation? Are they mathematically related?

Comment: @anrieff Thanks for the suggestion, will check.

Comment: @BrianDrummond I can't get the period of oscillation because I'm lacking an oscilloscope (working from home). There's a chance they are correlated yes.